# How to insert plastic ring bushing

Tags: automatic-transmission, mercedes-benz, bushing

I am trying to replace a plastic bushing and I can't figure out how to get it in. There must be some trick to it.  See photos below.

[image: original in]

[image: new in]

[image: none in]

Comment: Boil the part in water which should make it pliable enough to fit it into the rod end.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Note to posterity: you have a short time window it get it on after taking it out of the pot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boil the part in water which should make it pliable enough to fit it into the rod end.